# Return the corresponding value in multiple columns Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I've been trying to solve this in a clean manner, but have been failing remarkably on this task.

Going strait to the point... I have 2 dataframes:

```
df1
     anID   siID   daID
0       A      0      0
1       D      0      0
2       E      0      0
3       F      0      0
4       G      A      D
5       H      E      D
6       B      0      0
7       I      E      M
8       L      F      0
9       M      B      H
10      N      A      D

df2
   map_id  renum_id
0       A         1
1       C         2
2       B         3
3       E         4
4       D         5
5       F         6
6       Q         7
7       V         8
8       H         9
9       G        10
10      N        11
```

Basically, `df1` is a dataframe with identification codes, `df2$renum_id` has the new codes to replace the existing ones and `df2$map_id` is the map which to guide the recoding of `df1`'s columns.

Now I need a clean and light/fast way to get the corresponding `renum_id` value (using `map_id` as a key) for all 3 columns in `df1` (`anID`, `siID`, `daID`). Basically, I want it to give me the corresponding renum_ID for each letter, and keep the `0` (zero) for zeros in df1.

So, I need a `df3` like this:

```
     anID   siID   daID  anID/  siID/  daID/
0       A      G      0      1     10      0   
1       D      E      A      5      4      1      
2       E      0      0      4      0      0
3       F      B      D      6      3      5
4       G      A      D     10      1      5
5       H      E      D      9      4      5          
6       B      0      0      2      0      0     
7       N      A      D     11      1      5
```

It's probably something really simple, but I've been trying with `pd.merge` and couldn't come up with something to solve my problem.

Dataframes have something around hundreds of thousands of lines, that's why I insist in the need of a "light" way to solve it.

Thanks everyone in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can first create `dictionary` with `df2` by [`to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_dict.html) and then [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) values in `df1` by `dictionary` `d`. Last [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) new `DataFrame` `df3` to `df1` by columns:

```
d = df2.set_index('map_id').to_dict()
print d['renum_id']
{'A': 1, 'C': 2, 'B': 3, 'E': 4, 'D': 5, 'G': 10, 'F': 6, 'H': 9, 'N': 11, 'Q': 7, 'V': 8}

df3 = df1.replace(d['renum_id'])
df3.columns = [col + '/' for col in df3.columns]
print df3

   anID/ siID/ daID/
0      1     0     0
1      5     0     0
2      4     0     0
3      6     0     0
4     10     1     5
5      9     4     5
6      3     0     0
7      I     4     M
8      L     6     0
9      M     3     9
10    11     1     5

print pd.concat([df1, df3], axis=1)

   anID siID daID anID/ siID/ daID/
0     A    0    0     1     0     0
1     D    0    0     5     0     0
2     E    0    0     4     0     0
3     F    0    0     6     0     0
4     G    A    D    10     1     5
5     H    E    D     9     4     5
6     B    0    0     3     0     0
7     I    E    M     I     4     M
8     L    F    0     L     6     0
9     M    B    H     M     3     9
10    N    A    D    11     1     5
```

Comment: Awsome! That's just what I needed !!

Comment: Glad can help you! Good luck!